# ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'employee_id' for EmployeeSkill

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Have many to many relationship but keep getting the same error: ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'employee_id' for EmployeeSkill.  I've checked both my models and it seems like i have IDs for both so not sure what to do?

```
class Skill < ApplicationRecord

  validates :skill_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 30}
  validates_uniqueness_of :skill_name

  has_many :employee_skills
  has_many :employees, through: :employee_skills
end
```

...

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  #validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_many :employee_skills
  has_many :skills, through: :employee_skills
end
```

...

```
class EmployeeSkill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

Comment: Check your `schema.rb`, does EmployeeSkill have the `employee_id` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if in your migration files and database the corresponding id's are in place.

2) Restart the server (weird but sometimes is needed).

Your code looks good so I think is one of two cases I mention.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks, not sure exactly what you mean by check the migration files and DB.  i checked through the rails console and looks like there is an id associated:     "Employee Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "employees".* FROM "employees" ORDER BY "employees"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Employee id: 1, last_name: "Trial", first_name: "Test", employee_id: "1", email: "trial@example.com", level: "CEO", dept: nil, created_at: "2017-07-27 22:27:24", updated_at: "2017-07-27 22:27:24"> "

Comment: I mean that you can check the files that creates the migration under db/migrate. Also with the database I mean your actual database using rails console or the databas manger.

You can do a `db:reset` or `db:setup`  in order to clean your database. Then try again because maybe that record already exist before your new schema implementation.